# JSF - how to dynamically display values from messages.properties

Tags: jsf, el

I have a DataModel which has plan names and some other attributes.

I have different plans - gold , silver etc.
But I dont want to display Gold or Silver as it is. Based on the locale, I want to display it from the messages.properties

Here is my code snippet:

```
           <h:dataTable value="#{newMemberController.membershipModel}"   
            var="plans" styleClass="gird_header_value">
            <h:column><h:outputText value="#{plans.name}" /></h:column>
```

So instead of plans.name value I want something like #{msgs.#{plans.name}}
but this gives me a compilation error.

Does anyone know what is the correct syntax for this?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the brace notation to access `Map` values with a dynamic `key`: `#{map[key]}`.

Thus, the following example should do:

```
<h:outputText value="#{msgs[plans.name]}" />
```